Is there an equation to calculate the voltage spike caused by an inductor in the absence of a freewheeling diode?
I am using a 50V DC power supply to supply an inductive load of 10mH (any kind of inductive load.) I am using a MOSFET as a low side switch.
If I do not use a freewheeling diode to discharge the energy stored in the inductor, what is the numerical value of the spike cause at the intersection node of the inductor and the drain of the low side N-channel MOSFET when it is turned off? Is there an equation describing this?
Diagram given below.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Perhaps. But then you'd need at least 4 spatial and two dimensions of time worth of PDEs, these coupled to perhaps 11 dimensional ODEs, just to start to apprehend the beginnings of a quantitative result. And I'm sure that even then that wouldn't be including radiation transport or atomic collisions. So it gets worse from there. ;) Most engineers I've met seem to go more towards adding helpful parts to manage the situation over trying to solve those equations. Still, combining solid state and plasma physics might be an interesting, if perhaps somewhat less traveled path to explore...

The voltage at the drain when the MOSFET turns off depends on the peak current \$I_p\$ and the capacitance lumped at that node. Provided the breakdown voltage is high enough, the voltage will peak to a value set by the characteristic impedance of the network: \$V_{DS}=I_p\sqrt{\frac{L}{C_{lump}}}\$. A simple simulation lets you confirm this fact:

This is a purely theoretical result as the real capacitance is a nonlinear term and the switch does not turn off instantly. However, you see that having capacitance across the drain limits the peak excursion at the switch opening. This capacitor will then be discharged when the switch turns on and induces a loss, scaled by the switching frequency. Also, there is no body diode here, hence the swing below ground.

What sets the amount of peak current? How do I calculate it for a specific case?

First, a thank you would be appreciated : ) and the peak current depends on the time the switch remains closed. If you start from t = 0 and there is no current in the inductor, then its slope is $S=\frac{V_{in}}{L}$ in [A]/[s}. Then, the peak current is simply $I_p=St_{on}$ with $t_{on}$ the time during which the switch is closed.


Is there an equation to calculate the voltage spike caused by an inductor in the absence of a freewheeling diode?

The voltage will be "whatever it takes" to keep the current through the inductor continuous. Sometimes that means the voltage will rise to a level sufficient to break down some insulation, to cause a semiconductor junction to break down, or something similar.
The relationship between inductor current and inductor voltage is
$$V = LI'$$
If the current \$I\$ were to become discontinuous, (have a jump in value) then \$V\$ would become infinite. But obviously something will intervene (break down) to prevent that.

For the IRF530 the drain-source breakdown voltage is something  over 100V, so expect that.
An ideal inductor will do something non-sensical like produce infinite voltage and/or or self resonate at a gamma-ray frequency.
Real inductors are lossy and self resonate at lower frequencies so you will tend to see voltages in the general range of "too much" and self resonance in the range of "annoy radio users"

Theoretically with ideal inductor this voltage is infinite. But because of inductor parasitics and finite mosfet transient it should be about few hundred volts. This voltage is very hard to precisely calculate.

I think you mean "infinite"; "infinitive" is a grammatical term. But it's not infinite; theoretically it would be the MOSFET's BVdss.

@Hearth Corrected.

Yes there is a formula but you likely don't have the values required to use it.
V = L * di/dt.
So the voltage generated by inductance is proportional to the rate of the current change, i.e. how fast the transistor turns off. You likely have no number for this.
You can slow down the rate at which the transistor turns off, but depending on situation it might be not what you want to do for other reasons, such as dissipated energy in the switch transistor or because you need the solenoid coil to turn off fast.
Assuming the transistor is an ideal mechanical switch that breaks the circuit infinitely fast, i.e. in no time, the induced voltage is also infinte according to the formula.
The transistor cannot handle that high voltages and breaks down after it's rated voltage.
So that's why it is hard to predict.
In your circuit, there is also no coil resistance, so in theory when FET is on, the curren approaches infinity, only thing limiting it will be FET on resistance. If that is 100 milliohms, the current is limited to 500 A, also beyond the FET capabilities.
